# TensorFlow Lite Android Crashes on GPU Compute only when Input Size is >1

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've been working on an AndroidStudio app which uses TensorFlow Lite's GPU delegate to speed up inference speed.  It uses a model which takes an input array of size [n]x[384] and outputs an array of size [n]x[1], with n being the number of 384-sized inputs I wish to feed in at a given time.  Output n is only dependent on input n.  For n=1, I have no problems - TF Lite's CPU and GPU inference both work fine (albeit GPU does take longer - potentially because of the smaller input size?).  When I increase n so that it is greater than 1 and run my model, CPU compute works fine, however GPU compute crashes my program.  When I'm using an emulated Pixel 3 XL to run the program on I get this error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mlptest, PID: 10405
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply delegate: OpenCL library not loaded - dlopen failed: library "libOpenCL-pixel.so" not found
Falling back to OpenGL
TfLiteGpuDelegate Init: OpenGL ES 3.1 or above is required to use OpenGL inference.
TfLiteGpuDelegate Prepare: delegate is not initialized
Node number 4 (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) failed to prepare.
```

When I run GPU compute on my personal phone, a Motorla Moto G7 Power, I get this error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mlptest, PID: 16906
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: TfLiteGpuDelegate Init: Index is out of range
TfLiteGpuDelegate Prepare: delegate is not initialized
Node number 4 (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) failed to prepare.
```

This crash happens as soon as it the GPU Delegate's interpreter runs.  I'm creating the delegate using these lines of code:

```
                GpuDelegate delegate = new GpuDelegate();
            Interpreter.Options options = (new Interpreter.Options()).addDelegate(delegate);
```

Initializing the interpreter with the options then running it:

```
                Interpreter tfliteGPU = new Interpreter(loadedFile, options);
```

And finally closing the delegate after my computation:

```
delegate.close();
```

The original TensorFlow model I am using was made in TensorFlow 1.x and converted from a frozen graph using the tflite_convert command.  I'm running the app off of TF Lite 2.2.0 and TF Lite GPU 2.2.0:

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.2.0'
```

I've looked at TF Lite's [Android API reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/package-summary) and their page on the [GPU Delegate](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced) and have not found any relevant solutions.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Interesting! Is there a github repo to reproduce?

Comment: Is there any way you can share the model? It is difficult to gauge why the delegate fails unless we can peek at the model (maybe an untrained/simplified version of it?). Also GPU might not work on emulator, since the required drivers are not present AFAIK.

Comment: I'm working as an intern in a small research group which tasked me with putting their ML model on Android and running performance tests on it.  Currently I'm not allowed to share our whole model but I'll talk to my group at our weekly meeting on Wednesday and see if I can convince them otherwise.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please confirmed the GPU Delegate you are importing? Are you using 0.0.0-nightly?

Comment: I have updated my post with the TF Lite base and GPU implementation info.  I'm just using 2.2.0 but I will try nightly and update afterwards.

Comment: Good news!  Nightly seems to have solved the problem.  I've switched to it and now my code is running (albeit GPU compute is taking longer than CPU - but that's another bug for another day.)  I'll add an answer now and mark this as solved.  Thanks Hoi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a recommendation to try out the TensorFlow Nightly implementation:

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
```

I switched my implementation in build.gradle to use 0.0.0-nightly and my problem went away.  I can't speak as to what may have originally caused it, however this is what solved it.